# Hide y labels in pgfplots, and make coordinates fit inside of the pdfplot box

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to compare time spent on different simulation with bars from a pgfplot that show my simulation time. Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \pgfplotsset{width=10cm, height=5cm}
        \begin{axis}[ xbar, 
                      xmin=0, 
                      %width=12cm, 
                      %height=3.5cm, 
                      enlarge y limits=1, 
                      enlarge x limits=false,
                      xlabel={Temps [s]}, 
                      ylabel={},
                      symbolic y coords={itérative,mixte,analytique}, 
                      ytick=data, 
                      nodes near coords, 
                      nodes near coords align={horizontal}, 
                      legend pos = outer north east,    % Légende extérieure
            ]
            \addplot coordinates{(14.76,itérative)};
            \addplot coordinates{(9.19,mixte)};
            \addplot coordinates{(8.02,analytique)};
            \legend{CI itérative, CI mixte, CI analytique}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Cinématique inverse: Comparaison des temps de calculs entre la CI analytique, itérative et mixte]{
    Comparaison des temps de calculs entre la CI analytique, itérative et mixte.
    \label{fig:cininv:mixte-resultats-temps-calcul}
    }
\end{figure}
```

The result is: 
[image]

I do not want any text on the left; there is a 'iterative' label on the left. How is it possible to delete this?

I also want the biggest number (14.76) to be displayed inside of the box; how could i do this? using

```
enlarge x limits=0.2,
```

make the number fit inside of the box, but the axis is shifted (it starts at -2 instead of 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ytick=\empty` and `enlarge x limits={upper, value=0.2},`:

```
\documentclass[border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfplotsset{width=10cm, height=5cm}
        \begin{axis}[ xbar,
                      xmin=0,
                      %width=12cm,
                      %height=3.5cm,
                      enlarge y limits=1,
                      enlarge x limits={upper, value=0.2},
                      xlabel={Temps [s]},
                      ylabel={},
                      symbolic y coords={itérative,mixte,analytique},
                      ytick=\empty,
                      nodes near coords,
                      nodes near coords align={horizontal},
                      legend pos = outer north east,    % Légende extérieure
            ]
            \addplot coordinates{(14.76,itérative)};
            \addplot coordinates{(9.19,mixte)};
            \addplot coordinates{(8.02,analytique)};
            \legend{CI itérative, CI mixte, CI analytique}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]